# New to Node.js. Calling function from other file but node is printing whole file content

Tags: node.js

I have two files basic.js basic1.js. Please find code below :

basic.js :

```
console.log("My first node statement");
const sum =(a,b)=> a+b;
console.log(sum(1,1));
module.exports.sum =sum;
```

basic1.js :

```
const sum1= require('./basic');
const EventE= require('events');
const eventEmitter = new EventE();

eventEmitter.on('firstEvent',(a,b)=> {
  console.log(sum1.sum(a, b));
});

eventEmitter.emit('firstEvent',5,6);
```

on running basic1.js I am getting below output which seems incorrect as It should just called the function.

```
node basic1.js
My first node statement
2
11
```

Comment: `1+1` is `2`, which is the first log. `5+6` is `11` which is the second log. Am I missing something?

Comment: Importing the file will run that file code, and inside that file you have 2 console logs. And they are being called without you even calling sum()

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any way to just use the function. Even I am using       const sum1= require('./basic').sum;                                                                               Still It is printing whole file.

Comment: @prakashkumar Yes, move the function into another file and require it from both files that need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, anytime you require a module, it runs all of the top level statements in that module. This is so that any dynamically created/assigned objects, functions, constants, etc actually exist. It's very similar to adding a script to your webpage in a browser. You can either remove the console statements in your required file, or move them into a scope that is not automatically run (a function expression or a method, for instance).

Additionally in the comments, it was requested to be able to simply use the function. The reason this is occuring is because of this line:

```
module.exports.sum =sum;
```

Basically you are returning an object with a property named sum. This is because, by default and for simplicity, module.exports is an object with none of its own keys. In code terms, the module results as:

```
{
  sum: sum
}
```

To fix this, change the line to:

```
module.exports = sum;
```

Now, you are simply returning the function and only the function.